# what is the div at the origin of a radiating unit vector field

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a vector field of unit vectors radiating from the origin, i.e., $\vec v=\vec r/|r|$. Then what is ${\rm div}\ \vec v$ at the origin?

If we use the Gauss' Theorem we get $$\int_{B_r}{\rm div}\ \vec v\ {\rm d}x=\int_{\partial B_r}\vec v\ \cdot {\rm d}\vec S$$

The right hand side gives simply the area of the sphere $4\pi r^2$, and if we make an assumption that the div of $\vec v$ is continuous, the left hand side goes like $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 {\rm div}\ \vec v$, which means ${\rm div}\ \vec v$ blows up at the origin. Therefore, it should be in the form of a Dirac delta function $\delta({\vec r})$, but this will give a $4\pi r^2\delta(\vec r)$ which is $0$ in the sense of distribution. However, from intuition there is a source at the origin of the vector field.

What's the problem with my reasoning?

Comment: What is $v$ at the origin?  That is, what is $v$ when $r=0$?

Comment: @David I am not sure the value at a single point will influence the div, but make it a zero vector if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\nabla |r| = \frac{r}{|r|}$. So, in the sense of distributions, we would be asking for $\Delta |r|$. If you take the full distributional limit, we would get the distribution $\frac{n-1}{|r|}$ (this is a well defined distribution for $\mathbb{R}^n, \hspace{4 pt} n\geq 2$). So the only value it makes sense to assign to the divergence of that vector field at $0$ is infinity. Intuitively, this is because the vectors coming from the source never "lose strength" as they move out, so they had to be supplied by an infinite source.