# Distributional divergence of $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives, divergence-operator

I have the vector field
\begin{align*}
X:\mathbb R^d&\to\mathbb R^d\\
x&\mapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|}
\end{align*}
which is a differentiable vector field outside of the origin, and I am interested in its divergence. After some easy computation we get
$$
\mathrm{div}(X)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2\delta_0&d=1\\
\frac{d-1}{\|x\|}&d\geq 2.
\end{array}\right.
$$
The problem with the above computation is that the dimension 1 case is computed as a distributional derivative and the case of bigger dimension is computed classically.
This is a problem because for the longest time I thought that
$$
\mathrm{div}(X)
$$
should have a Dirac delta in the origin in any dimension, and I still believe it has to have it.

The reasons I do believe it has a Dirac delta component in the origin is because for $X$ infinite integral curves start from the origin.
To put it differently, if we were to look at $-X$, if one were to search for the solutions to the continuity equation for $-X$, i.e.
$$
\partial \mu_t+\mathrm{div}((-X)\mu_t)=0
$$
one would see how mass accumulates at the origin.

Question 1): did I make a mistake in my computations and $\mathrm{div}(X)$ has a Dirac delta in the origin? Or more correctly, if my computation isn't wrong classically but is wrong distributionally, how would I carry out that computation? Because it still doesn't yield a singular part when I evaluate with polar coordinates.

Question 2): is my intuition wrong and in reality in dimension bigger than one there is never a Dirac delta in that computation even distributionally?

Any help or literature is appreciated. Maybe it is all because my differential geometry skills are very rusty.

Comment: The origin would have a distribution that would need to be [infinitely larger than the Dirac delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342650/what-is-the-div-at-the-origin-of-a-radiating-unit-vector-field/3342654#3342654). The physical intuition is listed in the answer, but essentially viewing Dirac deltas as infinite is incorrect. Deltas represent *finite* sources at finite strengths compressed to a single point, thus they are a "density". Your vector field requires an infinite source or an "infinite strength" delta.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm not sure I get your point about the divergence being 'infinitely larger than delta'. Here, the divergence is given by a locally integrable function, which is a much milder type of singularity than a Dirac delta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The divergence you wrote is correct distributionally as well. To see this, let $\phi$ be any test function, then using the definition of distributional divergence, dominated convergence, and the divergence theorem, we get
\begin{align}
\langle\text{div}(X),\phi\rangle&:=-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle X^i,\partial_i\phi\rangle\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}X^i\partial_i\phi\,dV\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{B_{\epsilon}(0)^c}X^i\partial_i\phi\,dV\tag{DCT}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{B_{\epsilon}(0)^c}[(\partial_iX^i)\phi - \partial_i(X^i\phi)]\,dV\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left[\int_{B_{\epsilon}(0)^c}\frac{n-1}{\|x\|}\phi\,dV +\int_{S_{\epsilon}(0)}\phi\,dA \right]\tag{$*$}.
\end{align}
Notice that in this last equality, I used the divergence theorem, and beware that the outward normal to the boundary of $B_{\epsilon}(0)^c$ actually points into the origin, i.e is $-X$, so this extra minus sign cancels the minus sign which is already present. Now, in the first term, $\frac{1}{\|x\|}$ is integrable in a neighborhood of the origin in $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$, so we can use the dominated convergence theorem to say the first limit is $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{n-1}{\|x\|}\phi\,dV$. For the second term, since $n\geq 2$, the 'surface area' of the sphere $S_{\epsilon}(0)$ grows like $\epsilon^{n-1}$, which vanishes as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. So, the fact that $\phi$ is a test function means the intergal over the sphere vanishes too. Hence, the final result is
\begin{align}
\langle\text{div}(X),\phi\rangle&=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\frac{n-1}{\|x\|}\phi\,dV+0=
\left\langle\frac{n-1}{\|x\|},\phi\right\rangle.
\end{align}
Thus, even in the distributional sense, we have $\text{div}(X)=\frac{n-1}{\|x\|}$ for $n\geq 2$.

---

Note, the proof follows through up to $(*)$ even for $n=1$. To proceed further, note that if $n=1$, the first integral vanishes (this is just reflecting that $\frac{x}{|x|}$ is constantly equal to $\pm 1$ away from the origin, so the derivative vanishes there). In the 1-dimensional case, the "boundary sphere $S_{\epsilon}(0)$" really consists of a 2-point set $\{-\epsilon,\epsilon\}$, and the integral over this set just means adding the values of $\phi$ at these points $\phi(-\epsilon)+\phi(\epsilon)$. Now, taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$, and using continuity of $\phi$, we get $2\phi(0)= \langle 2\delta_0,\phi\rangle$, as expected.

Comment: Well then it means that Smirnov's theorem fails and I fail to see how. I will have to think what is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(This is in addition to the [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4460505/80734) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4459766/80734) answers: here, we give the 'correct' generalisation of $\operatorname{sgn}'=2\delta_0$ to higher dimensions. Put another way, we are answering your "question 2)".)

Your intuition is not quite right; as you go up in dimension, $1/|x|$ should be thought of as *less singular*. This is e.g. what's behind the fact that $1/|x|$ is integrable once $d>1$. Instead, $1/|x|^d$ is the correct threshold for (local) integrability.

Similarly, one should instead guess that $\DeclareMathOperator{\mydiv}{div} \mydiv(x/|x|^{d}) \newcommand{\dd}{\text d}  $ is the one with a delta for a (distributional) divergence. Indeed,
$$\fbox{$\mydiv\bigg(\frac x{|x|^{d}}\bigg) = \omega_{d-1} \delta_0.$} $$

($\omega_{d-1}=\int_{|x|=1}\dd \sigma$ is the surface area of $\Bbb S^{d-1}$.) The first sign of hope is that for all $x\neq 0$,
$$ \mydiv(x|x|^{-d})=\let\del\partial \del_i (x_i|x|^{-d}) = d|x|^{-d}+ x_i\cdot (-dx_i |x|^{-d-2}) = d|x|^{-d} - d|x|^{-d} =0. \tag{$\star$ }\label{1}$$
Now, from the definition of the distributional divergence,
\begin{align}
\left\langle\mydiv(x|x|^{-d}),\phi\right\rangle
&= -\int_{\mathbb R^d}\frac{x}{|x|^d} \cdot \nabla \phi(x) \, \dd x
\\ 
&= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{x}{|x|^d} \cdot \nabla \phi(x) \, \dd x
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\Bigg(\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\underbrace{\mydiv\Big(\frac{x}{|x|^d}\Big)}_{=0 \text{ by }\eqref{1}}  \phi(x) \, dx
- \int_{|x|=\epsilon} \frac{x\phi(x)}{|x|^d}\cdot n  \,\dd \sigma(x) \Bigg)\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|=\epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{|x|^{d-1}}\,\dd \sigma(x)
\end{align}
since $n= -x/|x|$ is the outward normal to $\{|x|>\epsilon\}$. Performing the change of variables $y= x/\epsilon$,
\begin{align}\left\langle\mydiv(x|x|^{-d}),\phi\right\rangle &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|y|=1} \phi(\epsilon y)\,\dd \sigma(y) \\
&= \phi(0)\int_{|y|=1}\,\dd \sigma(y)  + \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|y|=1}(\phi(\epsilon y)-\phi(0)) \,\dd \sigma(y)
\\
&=\langle \omega_{d-1}\delta_0,\phi\rangle,
\end{align}
where the limit is zero from the smoothness of $\phi$ (e.g. $|\phi(\epsilon y) - \phi(0)| \le \|\nabla \phi\|_{L^\infty} \epsilon$), showing the result.

Comment: (A quicker route for the same, if one is familliar with the Laplacian $\Delta = \operatorname{div}\operatorname{grad}$ is to take the gradient $\nabla F$ of the fundamental solution, i.e. the solution to $\Delta F=\delta_0$. )

Comment: I appreciate this addendum as I was thinking about the solutions to the Laplacian right after this question. Aside from this my intuition comes from the Smirnov's theorem as I apparently failed to explain at the bottom of my question. It tells you how 1-currents can be represented by an integral over currents on curves. It should be able to make me represent the divergence of a vector field with no periodic integral curves as the difference between the starting point of the solution of the related continuity equation and the ending point, which should be the dirac delta for big enough times.

Answer (score 2):

**Function Away from the Origin**

$\nabla\|x\|=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}
&=\frac{\nabla\cdot x}{\|x\|}-x\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|^3}\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{d}{\|x\|}-\frac1{\|x\|}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac{d-1}{\|x\|}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\nabla\cdot(av)=a\,\nabla\cdot v+v\cdot\nabla a$
$\text{(1b)}$: $\nabla\cdot x=d$
$\text{(1c)}$: simplify

**Distribution Supported at the Origin**

I had originally computed the part of the distribution supported at the origin using the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), but while trying to justify its application to a non-$C^1$ function, it became evident that I ended up computing the integral of the divergence without the theorem.

Let us compute the divergence of $\frac{x}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}}$, which is a $C^\infty$ approximation of $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\frac{x}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}}
&=\frac{d}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}}-x\cdot\frac{x}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{3/2}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{d-1}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{3/2}}\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: $\nabla\cdot(av)=a\,\nabla\cdot v+v\cdot\nabla a$
$\text{(2b)}$: $x\cdot x=x\cdot x+\epsilon^2-\epsilon^2$

Since $\frac{d-1}{\|x\|}$ is locally in $L^1$, the integral of $\frac{d-1}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{1/2}}$, the left summand from $\text{(2b)}$, over $B(0,r)$ vanishes uniformly as $r\to0$.

Consider the integral of the right summand from $\text{(2b)}$ over $B(0,r)$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{\epsilon^2}{(x\cdot x+\epsilon^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\omega_{d-1}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^r\frac{\epsilon^2}{(t^2+\epsilon^2)^{3/2}}\,t^{d-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3a}\\
&=\omega_{d-1}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\epsilon^{d-1}\int_0^{r/\epsilon}\frac1{(t^2+1)^{3/2}}\,t^{d-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3b}\\
&=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\left\{\begin{array}{}
2\,\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}}&\text{if $d=1$}\\
2\pi\epsilon\left(1-\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}}\right)&\text{if $d=2$}\\
4\pi\epsilon^2\left(\log\left(\frac{r+\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}}{\epsilon}\right)-\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}}\right)&\text{if $d=3$}\\
\omega_{d-1}\epsilon^2\left[0,\frac{r^{d-3}}{d-3}\right]_\#&\text{if $d\ge4$}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3c}\\[6pt]
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
2&\text{if $d=1$}\\[3pt]
0&\text{if $d\ge2$}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: convert to polar coordinates
$\phantom{\text{(3a):}}$ the "surface area" of $S^{d-1}$ is $\omega_{d-1}=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$
$\text{(3b)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t\epsilon$
$\text{(3c)}$: compute the integrals for $d=1,2,3$
$\phantom{\text{(3c):}}$ bound the integral for $d\ge4$
$\phantom{\text{(3c):}}$ where $[a,b]_\#$ represents a number in $[a,b]$
$\text{(3d)}$: evaluate the limits

**In Conclusion**

Putting together $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives
$$
\nabla\cdot\frac{x}{\|x\|}=\left\{\begin{array}{}
2\delta(x)&\text{if $d=1$}\\
\displaystyle\frac{d-1}{\|x\|}&\text{if $d\ge2$}
\end{array}\right.\tag4
$$

Comment: Doesn't the divergence theorem require a $C^1$ vector field to work? In general it might work with a $BV_{loc}$ function and since the vector field here appears to $L^1_{loc}$ it works of course, but to put it as an alternative shouldn't you prove it separately?

Comment: While justifying the use of the Divergence Theorem, it appeared easier simply to compute the contribution at the origin without the theorem.